# Android Java null pointer exception even if object instantiated

Tags: java, android

I have this code in an Android activity;

```
public static TwoWeeksActivity context;
public static DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two_weeks);

    RadCartesianChartView chartView = new RadCartesianChartView(this);

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
    rootView.addView(chartView);

    ArrayList<DateCountChart> vvv=new ArrayList<DateCountChart>();

    vvv=dbHelper.getCigCountTwoWeeks();
```

When I execute the app, when it arrives at tthis last line it returns java null pointer exception.

Why vvv is null? I have instantiated it:

```
ArrayList<DateCountChart> vvv=new ArrayList<DateCountChart>();
```

Please note that

```
 dbHelper.getCigCountTwoWeeks();
```

function in in dbhelper returns 
     ArrayList of DateCountChart object

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please also show your getCigCountTwoWeeks function

Comment: Have you instantiated the dbHelper? As it is most likley that object that returns null.

Comment: Do NOT keep a static activity field.

Comment: @vegaasen I forgot instantiating the dbHelper:        this.dbHelper=new DBHelper(this); Thanks!

Comment: In the last line, it doesn't even matter if you have already initialised vvv. As vegaasen said, it is dbHelper.

Comment: I agree with vegaasen, it seems that you have not instantiated dbHelper. In the other hand, this instantiation is useless `ArrayList<DateCountChart> vvv=new ArrayList<DateCountChart>();` if the following sentence is `vvv=dbHelper.getCigCountTwoWeeks();`. Just do `ArrayList<DateCountChart> vvv=dbHelper.getCigCountTwoWeeks();`

Comment: After instantiating dbHelper everything works. Thanks everyone! I cannot upvote you since I do not have 15 reputations yet.

Answer (score 0):

you should to instantiated dpHelper object.
I think this is the main problem.
also you can put logcat screen shot to review.